# Inverse Perspective Mapping -> When to undistort?

Tags: opencv, camera, projection, perspective, distortion

**BACKGROUND:**

I have a a camera mounted on a car facing forward and I want to find the roadmarks. Hence I'm trying to transform the image into a birds eye view image, as viewed from a virtual camera placed 15m in front of the camera and 20m above the ground. I implemented a prototype that uses OpenCV's warpPerspective function. The perspective transformation matrix is got by defining a region of interest on the road and by calculating where the 4 corners of the ROI are projected in both the front and the bird's eye view cameras. I then use these two sets of 4 points and use getPerspectiveTransform function to compute the matrix. This successfully transforms the image into top view.

**QUESTION:**

When should I undistort the front facing camera image? Should I first undistort and then do this transform or should I first transform and then undistort.

If you are suggesting the first case, then what camera matrix should I use to project the points onto the bird's eye view camera. Currently I use the same raw camera matrix for both the projections.

Please ask more details if my description is confusing!

Comment: You should undistort before doing the transform. Your distortion parameters are known for the original image. Attempting to apply them to a transformed image won't give a meaningful result.

Answer (score 0):

Class for creating inverse perspective mapping (IPM) views. Also called bird’s-eye view in the field of Advanced Driver Assistance Systems, or simple plane-to-plane homographies in projective geometry.

IPM CODE: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipmapping/files/?source=navbar

Reference: https://marcosnietoblog.wordpress.com/code/

Comment: citing code often helps others quickly understand the answer.